# Google cast v3 CAF receiver

Tags: android, chromecast

I am trying to use the CAF basic receiver app v3 to cast images, videos, and audios from my Android app. If I use the styled receiver app (default receiver), I can see that the Cast framework works correctly shows the images, video, audio on my TV. However, when I use the Custom CAF receiver app (the basic CAF receiver as given at: "[BasicReceiverCAF](https://github.com/googlecast/BasicReceiverCAF)"), only the images are shown. Video and Audio are not being played on TV. I wonder if the Basic receiver app is meant only for casting images and I need to include more for playing video, audio.